# How can I create a staff portal in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, intranet, microsoft

I am creating a SharePoint site for staff to access but I want to configure it so managers can upload things like employee contracts to a users profile so the user can access that document whenever they need to but it needs to be setup so only the user can access their own profile page and only the manager can upload documents to their profile.

Is this doable in SharePoint and if so what’s the best course of action to take?

Answer (score 0):

1.Microsoft 365 admin can manage user contact information in the Microsoft 365 admin center. Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Users -> Select the user -> Manage user contact information.

[image]

2.Reference about [how to make documents accessible in the Dev](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/store-your-documents-where-delve-can-get-to-them-49a0db49-5e6c-4dda-816e-e11dd77de49d).